# console would return array index number. I need Image path on console like this ../assets/images/circle1.png

Tags: react-native

State

```
list: [
                    { name: require('../assets/images/circle1.png') },
                    { name: require('../assets/images/circle2.png') },
                    { name: require('../assets/images/circle3.png') },
                ]
```

render item

```
_renderItem = (item, index) => {
        console.log('items====>', item)
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ selectedItem: item.item.name })}>
                    <Image key={index} source={item.item.name} style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

console return me the number

```
items====> 
{item: {…}, index: 2, separators: {…}}
index: 2
item:
**name: 5. <=====HERE IT RETURN ME NUMBER I NEED IMAGE PATH**
__proto__: Object
separators: {highlight: ƒ, unhighlight: ƒ, updateProps: ƒ}
__proto__: Object
```

HERE I NEED PATH OF IMAGE. BUT CONCOLE RETURN ME INDEX NUMBER ONLY

Comment: undefined when I use item.name

Answer (score 0):

This will always return number. If you need a path then you can do is

```
list: [ { name: '../assets/images/circle1.png' }, ...]
```

on render

```
<Image key={index} source={require(item.item.image)} style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}/.>
```

Comment: TransformError screens/HomeScreen.js: screens/HomeScreen.js:Invalid call at line 66: require(item.item.name)

Comment: Try this way require(item.name);

Comment: but I need image path ../assets/images/circle1.png like this on console

Comment: console give me arr index number instead of path

Comment: It's greate if it works, console this way like console.log('item path ====>', item.name)

Comment: name: 5 like this

Comment: How it's possible? Have you change your data list like --- list: [ { name: '../assets/images/circle1.png' }, ...] --- Are you sure you removed "require()" from data list?

Comment: ok then I call require in render item like this <Image source={require(item.item)} style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }} /> it give me syntax error

Comment: Yes, you have to use it like that. syntax error? what is it?

Comment: Invalid call at line 63: require(item.item.image)

Comment: Use -- require(item.name) -- instead of -- require(item.item.image) --

Comment: items====> ../assets/images/circle1.png

Comment: and now <Image source={require(item.item.image)} style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }} />

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: This way -- require(item.item.image) --- you got your result right?

Comment: i need path of that image

Comment: Why you need path of image? We just need to show image on view right? Can't you ignore the path in log?

Comment: I need a path because I need to combine two images so I require path